# Autofill form in external website with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to auto complete a form of a external website when i open it, the url is: https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/, and the id of the form is:  `ctl00_MainContent_txtLastName`

**JavaScript**

```
var web = window.open('https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/', '_blank');
       web.document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_txtLastName').value = 'Juan';
       console.log('succes');
```

I dont know if it is possible

Thanks

Comment: You want to open it from another browser page, a `node` program or something else? If you want to do it from the same page, it's not difficult. But I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: if the external website is not yours then not, only possible if the user local browser has auto filled, and the external site allow autofil, but its very limited to like name, email etc

Comment: This is impossible from another host. The only change you have is to make a browser extension but i'm sure that's too much for your problem.

Comment: the external website isn't mine, and i only want to put the name in the form